# Python thread running twice when called once in main

Tags: python, flask

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = threading.Thread(target = authtarget)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    print 'running thread'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This main is in our server, where app.run will start the server and will be able to handle requests. The thread we are making is a timer that checks a certain if statement every 5 seconds. However, t.start() will create two threads instead of only one. We've tried changing t.start() to t.run() however when we do that we never get to app.run, which we need to run the server.

```
def authtarget():
    sp  = Spotify()
    db = Database()
    resultList = []
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        sp.timer(204)
```

timer() is a function that we need called every 5 seconds.
However, with the code that we have currently, timer gets called twice instead of once every 5 seconds

Comment: a [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Following @Jean-FrançoisFabre's comment, what does `app.run()` do? That looks like the obvious suspect for a second thread of execution.

Comment: app.run() just runs some auxillary functions for the main part of the program. It does not have any thread calls though.

Comment: Is 'app' defined as an object from an external library, (i.e. Flask)? On, Flask for example, app.run with a debug flag may cause the app to load twice. If that's the case, a possible solution is to set an environment variable (using os.environ) when the thread starts, and quitting if it's already set so that the thread won't run twice.

Answer (score 25):

I just changed

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

to

```
app.run(debug=False)
```

so that it didn't run twice

Comment: I was facing a similar problem with bottle. Solved this by changing `reloader=False`.

Comment: Do you know why adding the debug true executes the thread twice?