# Thread executing function twice in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

Hi i am trying to run my flask app with one particular function at the same time. For that I am using `_thread`.
But when I start my server function called in `_thread.start_new_thread()` is called twice. I need to call it just once, any idea where is the problem?

```
def callPCo():
    requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5120/pco")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    _thread.start_new_thread(callPCo, ())
    app.run(host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5115", use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644083/python-thread-running-twice-when-called-once-in-main help?

Comment: @LarrytheLlama The answer there says to not use `debug=True`, but they're not doing that.

Comment: Yes that will be it Thanks. I am using `use_reloader=True`. It is probably similar to `debug=True`. So when i changed to False it executes just once